# Looking for an odd space movie from 80's or 70's

Tags: story-identification, space, empire

I remember seeing this movie as a kid some time in the late 80s, maybe early 90s (video rental). It's been a weird movie mixing space/science fiction and fantasy elements. The whole movie didn't take itself very serious.

The basic promise has been some good guys vs. an empire thingy (similar to Star Wars).

I only remember the following details:

- Strongest memory: Later on the evil guys control a planet or asteroid with some kind of giant engines attached, allowing them to move the whole thing.
- Early in the movie there's some kind of space chase. One of the heroes tries to get away from some kind of "space police" (i.e. some kind of fighter with attached flashing lights and some kind of police siren).
- Some time into the movie one character visits some lone house on a planet (I think seen as a silhouette with a tree next to it) being inhabited by some kind of witch to obtain some poison or whatever.

Comment: Starcrash [1978] seems to be close to this, anyone seen this movie?

Comment: My first thought was StarCrash too but the last point doesn't fit unless @Mario is conflating different movies in their memory

Comment: Yes, might be possible. Not sure. Who knows, maybe even someone recorded something over that tape back then. Will have a look.

Comment: It's definitely not been Starcrash... didn't remember David Hasselhoff being in there either. :D But that one looks interesting as well, might try to have a look. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm almost certain that it's [Message from Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078435/), Japan's own Star Wars clone.

- In the very beginning the hero and his partner are racing their star fighters, and being chased by a police officer.
- They visit an old lady to ask for advice (probably the witch you remember).
- Memory is hazy, but I recall the evil empire dude has an asteroid as a moving fortress.

It's a great cult SciFi movie and very fun if you don't take it too seriously. Here's a review:

http://www.movierapture.com/messagefromspace.htm

Comment: You're correct. Checked on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O7mOl5KkEw) and it's clearly the movie I remember. Didn't know it's been from Japan, but I clearly remember the main villain with his bleak face.

Comment: @Mario - Your question actually inspired me to watch it again, and luckily I found it on Netflix. Thanks!

Comment: I'm grabbing this ('Uchu kara no messeji'); good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I was sort of thinking starcommand or jason of starcommand but they were a series and not a movie.
Could be Space Precinct but that was more in the 90's.
Could also be Galaxina 1980.

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer describing why you think it could be one of these shows, including links as references if you have them. Thanks.